# How do I preserve LVM while changing the physical disk?

Tags: vmware, lvm

I had a problem with vm virtual disk used in lvm and I cloned it somewhere in the datastore with vmktools and then I want to use it same place instead of old one.

If I remove the the old disk from vm and add newly created clone disk, does lvm continue to work without data loss?

Comment: Are you using LVM inside the guest OS, and have the VM connected to a disk image file, or are you using LVM in the host OS, and have the VM connected to a logical volume?

Comment: "I cloned it somewhere in the datastore with vmktools and then I want to use it same place instead of old one."  I have NO idea what this is supposed to be communicating. Maybe you can try to clean this up a bit. Tell us what the 'same place' and 'old one' are, tell us which datastore, and clarify if it is a virtual hard drive that is stored on LVM or if the virtual hard drive is part of LVM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your cloned disk should work as you expect. The configuration for LVM is contained within the cloned disk and the cloned disk /boot partition.